# Can't find Autoprefixer in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I installed everything per this article: [Adding CSS Vendor Prefix Automatically With Sublime Text](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-automatic-vendor-prefix/)

I press CTRL-SHIFT-P, while am on a .CSS file and typing in "Autoprefixer", but such an extention I cant find - it is not in the list.

Anny Ideas?

Comment: I can very well see Autoprefixer in the list, it could be a problem with your internet connection or it might already be installed and just disabled.

Comment: Do you have the package manager installed ?